# Maven do not build the project from Intellij Idea

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea

I trying to build maven project with scala and java sources. So I run maven build from run cofigurations in Intellij Idea and it fail with message:

```
[ERROR] C:\SomePath\ScalaClass.scala:3: error: object fasterxml is not a member of package com
[ERROR] import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.{JsonProperty, JsonCreator} 

[ERROR] C:\SomePath\OtherScalaClass.scala:45: error: not found: type DateTime
[ERROR]                 someDate: DateTime,
```

There 2 crucial points wuith that:

1. `com.fasterxml.jackson` and joda-time dependency are already **downloaded** in maven repository and are **presented** in project pom.xml.
2. If I open console from  Intellij Idea and type `mvn clean install` the project builds **successfully**.

What the problem can be?

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml?

Comment: It is very big, but if you want some parts I can try. And again - from command line project is built.

Comment: Hmmmm. Ok. I am not a scala guy, but from the looks of the error, I immediatly thought 'missing dependency'

Comment: Post it on gist and update a link to your gist

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with effective pom. I use Russian Windows 7, so user directory contains russian symbols. So maven uses `.m2` from it's location, but Intellij Idea use %user_home%.m2 and can not load it well due to national symbols. I fix this with ovveriding Project settings->maven->Local repository property in Intellij Idea.

Also `mvn help:effective-settings` helps me :)

**P.S.** Why maven does not uses default ".m2" have not figured out yet.

Comment: Its just the default place it uses.  You can set M2_HOME